# Why the input and the button not taking the whole width of the div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code :

```css
.my-form {
  width: 100%
}

.search-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
}

.search-query {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 3%;
}

.search {
  background: #ea7d20;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" class="my-form">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="search">
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is a fiddle to view it live:
https://jsfiddle.net/nner02rk/2

I want the search input and submit input to take the full width of `.search-wrapper` or be centered inside the `search-wrapper` div.

Comment: @billynoah He is looking to fill that div, not the parent of that div, so it shouldn't matter what width the `.search-wrapper` div is.

Comment: @billynoah , Full width of the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to accomplish this depending on how you want the element widths distributed.  One way is to set the width of your button and use calc to make the input 100% less the specified button width:

```css
.my-form {
  width: 100%
}

.search-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
}

.search-query {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  width: calc(100% - 55px);
}

.search {
  background: #ea7d20;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" class="my-form">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="search">
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Another would be to use CSS table layout:

```css
.my-form {
  width: 100%
}

.search-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  display: table;
}

.search-wrapper>span {
  display: table-cell;
}

.search-query {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  width: 100%;
}

.search {
  background: #ea7d20;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" class="my-form">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <span><input type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search"></span>
    <span><input type="submit" value="search" class="search"></span>
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width attribute to the search-query and search classes.  Here is an example:

```
.search-query{
border-top-left-radius: 25px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
padding-left: 3%;
width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your `position: absolute` in `.search` and add `float: left` to both `.search-query` and `.search`.

```css
.my-form {
  width: 100%
}

.search-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
}

.search-query {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  float: left;
}

.search {
  background: #ea7d20;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  float: left;
  /* position: absolute; */
}
```

```html
<form method="GET" class="my-form">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="search" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="search">
    <div class="results"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , But it still the same , Try `.results{clear:both}` and you will see